# Jasper REST pass collection as parameter

Tags: rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report which receives a List parameter to use it in a IN clause:

`$X{IN, personID, _personID}`

The report works when running it through the web application or remote repository view in iReport.

Now I need to call it using the REST api. I have tried several different ways of passing the list value in my resource descriptor but none of them worked.

```
<resourceDescriptor name="Test_Report" wsType="reportUnit" uriString="/Test/Test_Report" isNew="false">

    <parameter name="_personId" isListValue="true"><![CDATA[1]]></parameter>

</resourceDescriptor>
```

The above example returns the following error:

`Invalid type java.lang.String for parameter _personId used in an IN clause; the value must be an array or a collection.`

I have also try the following:

```
<parameter>
<name>_personId</name>
<value isListValue="true">
    3
</value>
</parameter>
```

But this returns a report with all the records, not only the person with Id=3.

Answer (score 4):

My workaround for this problem was to use the REST V2 services of JasperServer.

Added to this the V2 has two advantages over the first version of the service:

- it doesn't require a resource descriptor
- it runs and exports the report in a single GET request

All the information required to run and export the report is passed through the request URL, for example:

`<host>/rest_v2/reports/Test/TestReport.html?_personId=3&_personId=4&_personId=5&_personId=6`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is totally fine, but there is also another small tip with collection type arguments ( **might be a bug**)

- If you have more than 1 item in the collection this is totally working correctly:
  `(3,4,5,6)->?_personId=3&_personId=4&_personId=5&_personId=6`
- If you have only 1 item in the collection you have to add empty one too:
  `(3)->?_personId=3&_personId=`

By the way, I am using Jasper Server CE 7.2.0 on the docker.

Comment: Hi @Onurus, I have your same problem, have you found some solution? Or have you open a ticket on jasperserver project? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @zaquas, 
No's to both of your questions. Error is originated from if you send just one element, the server tends to evaluate the item as a single item, I found that was an HTTP standard.

Comment: Thanks @onurus, I will have to investigate in the jasperserver source :)