# Passing collection parameter to JasperServer report via query string

Tags: jasper-reports, report, jasperserver

I'm trying to pass a collection parameter to a report. This report is shown inside an `IFRAME` and I'm passing the parameter this way:

I want to insert a report in an iframe in my web application.

The report has a "collection" parameter `IdTurno`. In the query-string I'm passing values this way:

```
http:jasper_server_url?ids=1,2,3
```

but this doesn't work.
What's the correct way to pass collection parameters via query string?
Can't find documentation about this.

**Note** I'm using JasperServer community edition v.5.1

Comment: Did you read [Jasper REST pass collection as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18701170/876298) post?